# Guzzle post json data causing 400 bad request

Tags: php, json, post, guzzle

I am trying to use guzzle to do a post request to an open API. I am also sending the post data as follows. For some reason i am getting a 400 bad request

```
$req = $client->request('POST',$this->base_url.'nutrients?app_id='.$this->app_id.'&app_key='.$this->api_key,[
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [
        "yield" => $portions,
        "ingredients" => [
            "quantity" => $portions,
            "measureURI" => "\"$f_uri\"",
            "foodURI" => "\"$m_uri\""
        ]
    ]
]);
$response = $client->send($req);
$decoded = json_decode($response->getBody());
dd($decoded);
```

The api documentation shows the method in curl as follows:
curl call:

```
curl -d @food.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/nutrients?app_id=${YOUR_APP_ID}&app_key=${YOUR_APP_KEY}"
```

food.json:

```
{
    "yield": 1,
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "quantity": 1,
            "measureURI": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_unit",
            "foodURI": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Food_11529"
        }
    ]
}
```

My links for measureURI and foodURI are generated correctly.

Comment: what is the $this->base_url?
is it $this->base_url = "h ttp s: / / api.edamam.com/api/food-database/"; 
?

Comment: var $base_url = "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/";

Comment: genesis - we don't use "var" for define variables in PHP.

Comment: yeah just changed it. Still not making a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do `->send()` after the `->request()`, it already returns an instance of `ResponseInterface`.

So just

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $this->base_url.'nutrients?app_id='.$this->app_id.'&app_key='.$this->api_key, [
        // ...
    ]
]);
$decoded = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```